# Firebase cloud function returning before function is complete

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, updates

I uploaded a cloud function to perform the update operation on multiple places in the database.

When I uploaded it was working fine but suddenly it stopped working and in the HTTP, it just returned `{}`.

I again looked at my code and found out that now the function is returning itself `{}`
before the function reached the end.

I don't know what suddenly happened it broke my whole application.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./myapp.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://myapp-b2365.firebaseio.com'
});

exports.quarter = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
     userType1 = admin.database().ref('users/Type1').once('value');
     userType2 = admin.database().ref('users/Type2').once('value');
     userType3 = admin.database().ref('users/Type3').once('value');
     userType4 = admin.database().ref('users/Type4').once('value');
    app_con = admin.database().ref('app_con').once('value');
     Promise.all([userType1, userType2, userType3, userType4, app_con]).then(result => {
        console.log(0);
        result[0].forEach(action => {
            action.ref.update({
                'AverageRating': (action.val().Rating  + action.val().AverageRating )/2,
                'Rating': 0
            })
        });
         console.log(1);
        result[1].forEach(action => {
             action.ref.update({
                 'AverageRating': (action.val().Rating  + action.val().AverageRating  )/2,
                 'Rating': 0
             })
         });
        console.log(2);
        result[2].forEach(action => {
            action.ref.update({
                'Rating': 0
            })
        });
         console.log(3);
        result[3].forEach(action => {
            action.ref.update({
                'Rating': 0
            })
        });
        let q = result[4].val().quarter;
        let y = result[4].val().year;
        if (q === 4) {
            q = 1;
            y = y+1;
        } else {
            q = q+1;
        }
        console.log(4);
        result[4].ref.update({
            'quarter': q,
            'year' : y
        })
       return res.send('Done');
    }).catch(error => {
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    })
});
```

Interesting thing is that out of the 4 `console.log()` i see only seeing

```
info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: 0
info: 1
info: 2
info: Execution took 291 ms, user function completed successfully
```

I don't know what is happening and how it is possible??

Comment: You're ignoring all the promises returned from the Firebase APIs you're calling. For HTTP type functions, you should only send a response after all the async work is fully complete, as indicated by the promises that the async method return.

Answer (score 3):

Your function has lots of async code, and it won't wait for everything to finish before exiting.

You can solve that by returning a promise and only resolving it after everything finishes, something like this:

```js
exports.quarter = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // return a promise so that the function will wait for it to resolve before exiting
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    userType1 = admin.database().ref('users/Type1').once('value');
    userType2 = admin.database().ref('users/Type2').once('value');
    userType3 = admin.database().ref('users/Type3').once('value');
    userType4 = admin.database().ref('users/Type4').once('value');
    app_con = admin.database().ref('app_con').once('value');
    const promises = [];
    Promise.all([userType1, userType2, userType3, userType4, app_con]).then(result => {
      console.log(0);
      result[0].forEach(action => {
        // add each async operation to a promise so that you can wait for them
        promises.push(action.ref.update({
          'AverageRating': (action.val().Rating + action.val().AverageRating) / 2,
          'Rating': 0
        }));
      });
      console.log(1);
      result[1].forEach(action => {
        promises.push(action.ref.update({
          'AverageRating': (action.val().Rating + action.val().AverageRating) / 2,
          'Rating': 0
        }));
      });
      console.log(2);
      result[2].forEach(action => {
        promises.push(action.ref.update({
          'Rating': 0
        }));
      });
      console.log(3);
      result[3].forEach(action => {
        promises.push(action.ref.update({
          'Rating': 0
        }));
      });
      let q = result[4].val().quarter;
      let y = result[4].val().year;
      if (q === 4) {
        q = 1;
        y = y + 1;
      } else {
        q = q + 1;
      }
      console.log(4);
      promises.push(result[4].ref.update({
        'quarter': q,
        'year': y
      }));
      // wait for all promises created
      Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        // only after everything completes you can resolve the promise, which causes the function to exit
        resolve(res.send('Done'));
      }).catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      reject(res.status(500).send(error));
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: it does not work, it still returns {} in HTTP.  WHAT EVER THE CASE IS, IT SHOULD ATLEAST RETURN 'Done' or server error.

Comment: I am using functions.https.onCall(async (data,context) => {}) and 
finished with status code: 200  before return statement

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo Smania is totally right: you have to use promises (and in your case `Promise.all()`) in order to wait for all the asynchronous work to be finished before sending back the response.

The following adaptation of Ricardo's code should work:

```
exports.quarter = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // return a promise so that the function will wait for it to resolve before exiting

    userType1 = admin
      .database()
      .ref('users/Type1')
      .once('value');
    userType2 = admin
      .database()
      .ref('users/Type2')
      .once('value');
    userType3 = admin
      .database()
      .ref('users/Type3')
      .once('value');
    userType4 = admin
      .database()
      .ref('users/Type4')
      .once('value');
    app_con = admin
      .database()
      .ref('app_con')
      .once('value');

    Promise.all([userType1, userType2, userType3, userType4, app_con])
      .then(result => {
        const promises = [];
        console.log(0);
        result[0].forEach(action => {
          // add each async operation to a promise so that you can wait for them
          promises.push(
            action.ref.update({
              AverageRating:
                (action.val().Rating + action.val().AverageRating) / 2,
              Rating: 0
            })
          );
        });
        console.log(1);
        result[1].forEach(action => {
          promises.push(
            action.ref.update({
              AverageRating:
                (action.val().Rating + action.val().AverageRating) / 2,
              Rating: 0
            })
          );
        });
        console.log(2);
        result[2].forEach(action => {
          promises.push(
            action.ref.update({
              Rating: 0
            })
          );
        });
        console.log(3);
        result[3].forEach(action => {
          promises.push(
            action.ref.update({
              Rating: 0
            })
          );
        });
        let q = result[4].val().quarter;
        let y = result[4].val().year;
        if (q === 4) {
          q = 1;
          y = y + 1;
        } else {
          q = q + 1;
        }
        console.log(4);
        promises.push(
          result[4].ref.update({
            quarter: q,
            year: y
          })
        );

        return Promise.all(promises);
      })
      .then(result => {
        res.send('Done');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error);
      });

});
```

I would suggest that you watch this official video series for more detail: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ (in particular the first video of the 3 videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises").

Comment: @Rahul Hello, did you have time to look at this anwser?

Comment: I am using functions.https.onCall(async (data,context) => {}) and 
finished with status code: 200  before return statement